# ¿Como hago para que todo el programa pase en una misma ventana?

Tags: python, tkinter

me gustaría saber como hago para que mi programa no vaya abriendo diferentes ventanas, sino que pase todo en una. Y estaría muy bien poder poner un botón de retroceso para tirar para atrás. Gracias!

Uso **tkinter**, tengo un sistema de login y sign up y seguido se abre una ventana con un par de botones.
Os pongo el programa entero, lo único que necesito es que no se vayan abriendo ventanas, que pase todo en una...

```
from tkinter import *
import os
import tkinter

def delete2():
    screen3.destroy()

def delete3():
    screen4.destroy()

def delete4():
    screen5.destroy()


def sessionButton1():
    screen9 = Toplevel(screen)
    screen9.title('Administrator')
    screen9.geometry("600x400")
    Label(screen9, text = "ADMINISTRATOR", fg = "white", bg = "black", width = 
    "600", height = "2", font = ("NasalizationRg-Regular", 10)).pack()
    lineaAbajo = Label(screen9, text = "", bg = "black", width = "600", height 
    = "2")
    lineaAbajo.pack(side = 'bottom')


def session():
    screen8 = Toplevel(screen)
    screen8.title("Operation Center")
    screen8.geometry("600x400")
    Label(screen8, text = "Welcome to the Operation Center", fg = "white", bg 
    = "black", width = "600", height = "2", font = ("NasalizationRg-Regular", 
    10)).pack()
    Label(screen8, text = "").pack()
    Button(screen8, text = "ADMINISTRATOR", fg = "white", width = 30, height = 
    2, bg = "SpringGreen2", font = ("Arial Rounded MT Bold", 10), command = 
    sessionButton1).pack()
    Label(screen8, text = "").pack()
    Button(screen8, text = "HACK PASSWORDS", fg = "white", width = 30, height 
    = 2, bg = "SpringGreen2", font = ("Arial Rounded MT Bold", 10)).pack()
    Label(screen8, text = "").pack()

    Button(screen8, text = "(NOT DEFINED)", fg = 'white',
                                            width = 15, 
                                            height = 5, 
                                            bg = "SpringGreen2", 
                                            font = ("Arial Rounded MT Bold", 
                                            10)).pack()




def login_success():
    session()

def password_not_recognised():
    global screen4
    screen4 = Toplevel(screen)
    screen4.title("Success")
    screen4.geometry("150x100")
    Label(screen4, text = "Password not recognized").pack()
    Button(screen4, text = "OK", command =delete3).pack()

def user_not_found():
    global screen5
    screen5 = Toplevel(screen)
    screen5.title("Success")
    screen5.geometry("150x100")
    Label(screen5, text = "User not found").pack()
    Button(screen5, text = "OK", command =delete4).pack()


def register_user():

    username_info = username.get()
    password_info = password.get()

    file = open(username_info, "w")
    file.write(username_info+"\n")
    file.write(password_info)
    file.close()

    username_entry.delete(0, END)
    password_entry.delete(0, END)

    Label(screen1, text = "Registration Successful", fg = "green", font = 
    ("calibri", 11)).pack()

def login_verify():
    username1 = username_verify.get()
    password1 = password_verify.get()
    username_entry1.delete(0, END)
    password_entry1.delete(0, END)

    list_of_files = os.listdir()
    if username1 in list_of_files:
        file1 = open(username1, "r")
        verify = file1.read().splitlines()
        if password1 in verify:
            login_success()
        else:
            password_not_recognised()
    else:
            user_not_found()

def register():
    global screen1
    screen1 = Toplevel(screen)
    screen1.title('Register')
    screen1.geometry('400x250')
    global username
    global password
    global username_entry
    global password_entry
    username = StringVar()
    password = StringVar()

    Label(screen1, text = "Please enter details below").pack()
    Label(screen1, text = "").pack()
    Label(screen1, text = "Username").pack()
    username_entry = Entry(screen1, textvariable = username)
    username_entry.pack()
    Label(screen1, text = "Password").pack()
    password_entry = Entry(screen1, textvariable = password)
    password_entry.pack()
    Label(screen1, text = "").pack()
    Button(screen1, text = "Register", width = 30, height = 1, fg = "white", 
    bg = "SpringGreen2", command = register_user).pack()

def login():
    global screen2
    screen2 = Toplevel(screen)
    screen2.title("Login")
    screen2.geometry("400x250")
    Label(screen2, text = "Enter details below to login", bg = "black", width 
    = "600", height = "1", fg = "white", font = ("NasalizationRg-Regular", 
    10)).pack()
    Label(screen2, text = "").pack()

    global username_verify
    global password_verify

    username_verify = StringVar()
    password_verify = StringVar()

    global username_entry1
    global password_entry1

    Label(screen2, text = "Username").pack()
    username_entry1 = Entry(screen2, textvariable = username_verify)
    username_entry1.pack()
    Label(screen2, text = "").pack()
    Label(screen2, text = "Password").pack()
    password_entry1 = Entry(screen2, textvariable = password_verify)
    password_entry1.pack()
    #password_entry1.bind('<Return>', login_verify)
    #password_entry1.config(command = login_verify)

    Label(screen2, text = "").pack()
    Button(screen2, text = "Login", width = 30, height = 1, fg = "white", bg = "SpringGreen2", command = login_verify).pack()



def main_screen():
    global screen
    screen = Tk()
    screen.geometry("400x250")
    screen.title("OPERATION CENTER 1.0")
    Label(text = "Operation Center", bg = "black", width = "300", height = 
    "2", fg = "white", font = ("NasalizationRg-Regular", 13)).pack()
    Label(text = "").pack()
    Button(text = "Login", fg = "white", height = "2", width = "30", bg = 
    "SpringGreen2", font = ("Arial Rounded MT Bold", 10), command = 
    login).pack()
    Label(text = "").pack()
    Button(text = "Register", fg = "white", height = "2", width = "30", bg = 
    "SpringGreen2", font = ("Arial Rounded MT Bold", 10), command = 
    register).pack()
    Label(text = "").pack()
    Label(text = "").pack()
    ooof = Label(text = "© ErPomes")
    ooof.pack(side = 'bottom')

    screen.mainloop()

main_screen()
```

Y hasta aquí.

Se que es mucho código pero es que no se hacerlo de otro modo, a ver si me podeis ayudar..., grácias!

Comment: Deberías mostrar tu código, sino completo, al menos una versión "simplificada" que pueda ejecutarse y que muestre el problema que describes. ¿A qué te refieres con que abre diferentes ventanas? ¿Usas alguna librería para ello como Tkinter, PyQT, wxpython, etc.? ¿O te refieres a las ventanas que abre tu propio sistema operativo si haces doble click sobre el archivo .py? En este último caso no veo razón para que abra más de una ¿qué haces en tu programa para que abra otras?

Comment: Uso tkinter, tengo un sistema de login i sign up y seguido se abre una ventana con un par de botones

Comment: Ok, ya se va centrando la pregunta. Lo mejor sería que la editaras para añadirle esta información, en lugar de dejarla en los comentarios, de modo que cualquiera que quiera ayudar tenga toda la información necesaria en un solo lugar (la pregunta). De paso ¿puedes añadir algo de código que muestre la estructura de tu aplicación? Idealmente no se trataría de tu aplicación completa, sino del mínimo necesario para que cualquiera pueda probar a ejecutarla en su ordenador, y vea lo que ocurre, para determinar cómo podría resolverse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Abres una nueva ventana cada vez que llamas a `Toplevel(screen)`.

La forma de evitarlo es usar siempre la misma `screen` en lugar de crear una nueva cada vez. Tal como tienes el código ahora mismo, la forma más rápida de cambiarlo para ver si el truco te funciona sería la siguiente:

Busca en todo tu código cada vez que haces algo del estilo de lo siguiente (pero con `screen2`, `screen3`, etc. también):

```
screen1 = Toplevel(screen)
```

Y cámbialo por esto otro:

```
clear_window(screen)     # Eliminar todos los "hijos" creados en esta ventana
screen1 = screen         # Y hacer que la nueva ventana sea la anterior
```

Es decir, en vez de crear una nueva `screen1` usando `Toplevel(screen)`, simplemente asigna como nueva ventana la original `screen`. El problema es que el contenido que añadas a la ventana (etiquetas, botones, etc.) se añadirá *sobre el que ya había*, cosa que no quieres, de modo que antes hay que eliminarlo todo y por eso la llamada a `clear_window(screen)` que sería una función que implementarías así:

```
def clear_window(root):
    for l in root.pack_slaves():
        l.destroy()
```

De este modo la misma ventana se "reusa" para todas tus "pantallas". No obstante, no hay forma de "volver atrás". Tendrías que implementar un botón adicional en cada ventana cuyo `command` invoque a la función adecuada para re-crear la "pantalla anterior".

Si compruebas que con esta modificación "rápida y sucia" se comporta como quieres, tocaría ponerse a refactorizar (es decir, reescribir) el código para dejar de usar las variables `screen1`, `screen2`, etc. y tener sólo `screen`.

Comment: funciona perfecto!! , pero no se como poner el botón de return...